# Remove first occurence of elements in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array:

`a = np.array([-1,2,3,-1,5,-2,2,9])`

I want to only keep values in the array which occurs more than 2 times, so the result should be:

`a = np.array([-1,2,-1,2])`

Is there a way to do this only using numpy?
I have a solution using a dictionary and dictionary filtering, but this is kind of slow, and I was wondering if there was a faster solution only using numpy.

Thanks !

Comment: You can use `np.unique` to find and count the occurrence of a value

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([-1, 2, 3, -1, 5, -2, 2, 9])
values, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
values_filtered = values[counts >= 2]
result = a[np.isin(a, values_filtered)]
print(result)  # return [-1 2 -1 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1, 2, 3,4,4,4,1])

filter_arr = [np.count_nonzero(arr == i)>1 for i in arr]

newarr = arr[filter_arr]

print(filter_arr)
print(np.unique(newarr))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot!

All answers solved the problem, but the solution from Matvey_coder3 was the fastest.

KR

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).